# Invalid format of Export utility name

Tags: oracle11g, cron, rhel

I am trying to add backup script to the crone job that would run every 2 min (will be changing to 11 night for everyday).
I am getting below as the log.

```
[![error content][1]][1]


Message 206 not found; No message file for product=RDBMS, facility=EXP: release 11.2.0.1.0 - Production on Mon Dec 10 16:46:01 2018

Copyright (c) 1982, 2009, Orac

Invalid format of Export utility name

Verify that ORACLE_HOME is properly set

Export terminated unsuccessfully

EXP-00000: Message 0 not found; No message file for product=RDBMS, facility=EXP[
```

My cron entry is

```
 */1 * * * * sh /oracle/backups/fts.sh > /oracle/backups/ftscron.log 2>&1
```

The content of fts.sh is

```
#!/bin/sh
#!/usr/bin/bash

# Backups of hrmsfas, estate, ftsys, incpkg

/oracle/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1/bin/exp ftsys/ftsys file=/oracle/backups/ftsys.dmp log=/oracle/backups/ftsys.log owner=ftsys "STATISTICS=NONE"
```

When I am executing the statement on terminal I am getting the script executed successfully.

[image: error content]

Comment: Please post text rather than images. But did you read the error messages - "Verify that ORACLE_HOME is properly set". When you run through crno you have to include the environment set-up in your script, it doesn't inherit anything from your normal interactive shell. (Also, is there a reason you're using old `exp`, not modern `expdp`?)

Comment: [Possible duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17922688/266304) - it's for SQL\*Plus not `exp` (or `expdp`!) but the principle is the same.

Comment: @AlexPoole the oracle home points to /oracle/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1  and the oracle application is already live.

Comment: You know that, and your interactive shell knows that, since it works there. But the shell script being run via cron does not know that - you have to set up the environment in that cron context, so it has `ORACLE_HOME` and other relevant environment variables defined.

Comment: @AlexPoole I have added to the script file but still same problem.         
 export ORACLE_HOME= /oracle/app/oracle/product/
export PATH = $PATH:$ORACLE_HOME

Comment: Well, that isn't the full path for your home... Did you look at the link to the duplicate? You can use `oraenv` to set up the whole environment.

Comment: @AlexPoole I followed the link and the oraevn and setting the environment locally within the script worked. Thanks !

Comment: I admit that the solution is same as the link provided so this question can be regarded as duplicate. Is there any way to remove the post or shall it be as it is.

Comment: I've already marked it as a duplicate. [It's OK to leave it as it is](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/32311/152099), as it will act as a signpost for someone in the future searching for say 'cron' and 'export' or the exact error you got - which probably wouldn't find the other question, since that's referring to SQL\*Plus.